# Half of the window in one workspace and the other half in another one

Tags: mate-desktop, workspaces

I have an application that runs in an embedded system with 2 screens. However, in my development environment I only have one monitor, so in order to debug the application I used to run the desktop with two workspaces, and then I would place my app window in a manner that half  of it would be placed in one workspace and the other half in another one, so I could easily navigate using the CTRL+ALT+arrows combination.

However, since I've installed MATE in my Ubuntu, I am unable to do it. When I switch to the other workspace, it opens so me completely blank, without the other half of the window on it.

How can I keep an window between multiple workspaces using MATE?

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, the bahaviour you are getting now is the behaviour I would want, yet don't get!

It's not pretty, but you could run your application on a VNC display that is sized as wide as 2 screens. Then you run two different VNC viewers connected to the same display, each the width of one screen. One of them is scrolled to the left using the horizontal scrollbar and the other to the right.